# What is mean by Seeding in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have understand the Database Eloquent ORM but not understanding seeding meaning in context of Database.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel includes a simple method of seeding your database with test data using seed classes. All seed classes are stored in the database/seeds directory. Seed classes may have any name you wish, but probably should follow some sensible convention, such as UsersTableSeeder, etc.

By default, a DatabaseSeeder class is defined for you. From this class, you may use the call method to run other seed classes, allowing you to control the seeding order.

For ref, please see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding

Answer (score 0):

Database seeding is the initial seeding of a database with data. With Laravel, this is easily automated by using the built in Seeder class and artisan command.

Comment: Except when he says he already understands seeding, "but... not... in [the] context of Database".